# How to fix error while adding firebase cloud messaging dependency to build.gradle file

Tags: android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add firebase cloud messaging dependency to Gradle.build file and it showing an error. Even though I try to add the latest version (20.0.0), still it shows an error. Please help me with my problem.

I have changed the versions to the latest version of firebase cloud messaging as well as all other dependencies in gradle.build file.

```
repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'

}
```

The error showing is shown below:

```
ERROR: In the project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
```

1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. The behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 17.0.0.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.3
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop@{strictly 16.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common@{strictly 16.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection@{strictly 15.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@20.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl@{strictly 17.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@{strictly 16.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@{strictly 16.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@16.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database@4.1.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@{strictly 15.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@{strictly 20.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@{strictly 17.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl@{strictly 16.2.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@{strictly 16.0.3}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@{strictly 16.0.3}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@{strictly 16.0.3}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@{strictly 17.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop@{strictly 17.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@{strictly 20.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@{strictly 17.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database@{strictly 16.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats@{strictly 17.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-common@{strictly 19.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database@{strictly 4.1.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection@{strictly 16.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database@16.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@16.0.3
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector@{strictly 18.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags@{strictly 15.0.1}

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

- The problem is here

  Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[ 15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 17.0.0.
- You need to update the version of gms:play-services-flags.

  `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:17.0.0'` or higher

  (ref: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

  I hope it helps you.